# UIScrollView zoomToRect not working

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView with pagingEnabled on and I want to (using like a button or something) animated(ly) zoom to each page. I am using zoom to rect, but that's not working. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset animated:(BOOL)animated` instead as you (probably) do not want to change view's zoom anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to scroll a `page`of the paged scroll view (assuming that all pages have equal width):

```
CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
frame.origin.y = 0;
[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had forgotten to connect the UIScrollView's delegate in the storyboard. Therefore zoomToRect did not work.